# How do you delete a Json object by id in node Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a Mongodb collection named "EVENTS" and in the collection i have an object of array which looks like this:

```
{
   "Events":[
      {
         "_id":"53ae59883d0e63aa77f7b5b2",
         "Title":"Title Blank",
         "Desc":"Description Blank",
         "Date":"2014-06-04 00:30",
         "Link":"http://googleparty.com",
         "Event":"Victoria Centre",
         "dateCreated":"28/6/2014  06:58"
      },
      {
         "_id":"53ae59883d0e63aa77f7b5b3",
         "Title":"Hello World",
         "Desc":"hello",
         "Date":"2014-06-04 00:30",
         "Link":"http://linkedinparty.com",
         "Event":"social",
         "dateCreated":"30/2/2014  11:10"
      }
   ]
}
```

how would i delete an object by id in node.js so " delete(53ae59883d0e63aa77f7b5b2)" will yield this:

```
{
       "Events":[
           {
         "_id":"53ae59883d0e63aa77f7b5b3",
         "Title":"Hello World",
         "Desc":"hello",
         "Date":"2014-06-04 00:30",
         "Link":"http://linkedinparty.com",
         "Event":"social",
         "dateCreated":"30/2/2014  11:10"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you really want to do is "empty" the array then you just need to use the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator with an `.update()` and "set" the array as an empty one:

```js
db.collection.update({},{ "$set": { "Events": [] } },{ "mutli": true})
```

So the `.update()` operation takes a "query" to select the documents in your collection, a blank query as shown selects everything. The "update" section contains the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operation that just replaces the current "Events" field with an empty array.

The "multi" option there makes sure this is applied to every document that matches. The default is `false` and will only update the first document that matches.

For more specific operations removing selected array elements, look at the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator. Your edit shows now that this is what you want to do:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "Events._id": ObjectId("53ae59883d0e63aa77f7b5b2") },
    { "$pull": { "Events": { "_id": ObjectId("53ae59883d0e63aa77f7b5b2") } } }
)
```

But your inclusion of arrays with `_id` fields seems to indicate that you are using mongoose, so the ObjectId values are cast automatically:

```js
Model.update(
    { "Events._id": "53ae59883d0e63aa77f7b5b2" },
    { "$pull": { "Events": { "_id": "53ae59883d0e63aa77f7b5b2" } } },
    function(err,numAffected) {

    }
);
```

Comment: quite close but im not trying to empty the array, I'm just trying to delete an object with an id. Sorry for the misleading example :)

Comment: @Pizzy213codes Then what are you trying to do? It sure looks like you are trying to empty the array by your question. Perhaps you should update that to say what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: sorry once again for the example i gave earlier, i just updated the question, please take a look :)

Comment: @Pizzy213codes And answered. I did make reference to  the `$pull` operator. There is now an example of how to use it.

Comment: @neilLuun if i may ask, please how do i handle events like button click to be able call a function in node.js?

Comment: @Pizzy213codes That really is another question that is also to broad to ask based on just a comment. You are better off asking a another question that details what you are trying to do.